# MVC's AntiForgeryToken in ajax call and IsAjaxRequest() method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This may be a silly question but I've been thinking about this for a while. Maybe I am forgetting some details about how this all works and, of course, I have not tested this scenario.

Imagine a simple JsonResult action example in a ASP.NET MVC project, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult greetingMsg(string name, string timeOfDay)
{
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return null;
    return Json(new { result = $"Hello {name}, good {timeOfDay}" });
}
```

Of course, we should send the AntiForgeryToken in the Ajax call, or this method will not execute.

This JsonResult method may be called from anywhere on the web, but it will fail because of the AntiForgeryToken not matching, right? Ok, if we take out the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute, will the method execute when called by another site on the web using Ajax, or do Ajax calls can only be successful when called within the same web?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the AntiForgeryToken it will work from anywhere. unless you restrict your application with delegating handler or other security mechanism that will check for origin. But then you could also spoof it.

I had to find a solution to a similar problem where they asked for AntiForgeryToken but we were building a pure javascript SPA so no ASP.NET MVC (Web api on a server and the SPA on another). The only way to make it work safely was to introduce OAuth2 JWT. (since the issuer is signed inside the token for JsonWebToken you can't fake it) then anyone wanting to call your api must be able to get a token from you.